# How to store a primary key in a session variable

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am storing an `object.pk` in a session variable.

E.g. in template.html:

```
{{ request.session.myobject_pk }} <-- results in a numeric value e.g. 10
{{ myobject.pk }} <-- the same numeric value, 10
```

However, when I call these two values in an `if` statement, the primary key does not match the session variable:

```
{% if myobject.pk == request.session.myobject_pk %} <-- results in a False
```

Why is this? Is the object an integer and the session variable a string? How can I fix this to use them both in a conditional logic statement like this?

**EDIT**

I set the session variable in a view:

```
class MyView(ProcessFormView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post_myobject_pk = request.POST.get('field_name')
        ...
        // do stuff
        ...
        request.session['myobject_pk'] = post_myobject_pk
```

Comment: Can you debug the values in your view? They may be different types that just have the same string representation. The string `'10'` and integer `10` for example

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes I've done this, they are both identical.

Comment: What are they? What's the result of `print(type(request.session.myobject_pk), type(myobject.pk))`?

Comment: @IainShelvington thanks, how would I execute that command? In a view?

Comment: @alias51 yes, maybe in the `get_context_data` method`

Comment: @IainShelvington Unfortunately that appears to result in `None` for both..? They are clearly displaying in the template though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values in the POST dictionary will always be strings, you need to cast the value to an `int`

```
post_myobject_pk = int(request.POST.get('field_name'))
```